# Get child terms of a particular taxonomy term using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I'm having trouble with [SharePoint CSOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#basic-operations-with-the-sharepoint-net-client-object-model) getting child terms using [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.term.aspx) object's [GetTerms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.termsetitem.getterms.aspx) method. In PowerShell using [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) I do this:

```
PS C:\> $term = Get-PnPTerm -Identity "Regions" -TermSet "Location" -TermGroup "Common"
PS C:\> $childTerms = $term.GetTerms(100)
PS C:\> $term.Context.Load($childTerms)
PS C:\> $term.Context.ExecuteQuery()

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: lcid"
At line:1 char:1
+ $term.Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

I get the same error when I do this inside ASP.NET MVC application representing remote web in my SharePoint provider-hosted add-in.

Comment: Are you trying to get all terms inside the TermSet or a Term?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the code of [PnP GetTerm function @ GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Taxonomy/GetTerm.cs) you will get better understanding of the command.

**Update : Solution to your problem**

I am having [PnP's October 2017 Intermediate Release 2](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases). They way you load the term object is causing problem. Follow below code it should work.

```
$term = Get-PnPTerm -Identity "Regions" -TermSet "Location" -TermGroup "Common"
$ctx = $term.Context
$ctx.Load($term.Terms)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$term.Terms ## This should list all child terms
```

Comment: I need to get all child terms under particular term in a term set, not all the terms from that term set

Comment: @Rustam once you get all terms, can you not manipulate the terms and retrieve your desired ones.

Comment: I'm interested in how to use the API method I asked about.

Comment: @Rustam Check the updated answer, it should work.

Comment: The Terms property only contains child terms directly under the main term. I have a tree structure of child terms and need to get them all recursively